# If a vampire drinks blood of a sick human, does the vampire get infected?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, disease

I'm a vampire, and I'm stupidly hungry, not to mention stupidly stupid. I feed on a random stranger, and, who would've thought - that stranger is HIV positive.

Am I all set for a healthy dose of vampire AIDS? Am I not? Is it disease-specific or universal?

Comment: Hi, Ivan! Can you tell us what version of the game this ostensible vampire comes from? (The rules in Vampire Fifth Edition may differ from those in Revised or V20.) And, welcome to the site!

Comment: @Jadasc From what I see, I've received answers for basically every major version, so I suppose that's obsolete now?

Comment: @IvanT, it's *always* a good idea to tag with the exact system you're asking about. Even after you've got an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

HIV and other bloodborne contagions are known to be transmitted by vampires since 1st Edition. It simply makes a Vampire HIV positive. He won't ever show all the usual symptoms of AIDS, but he will submit the disease if he isn't careful, and could get some other downsides from the illness destroying his Vitae. Below you find the relevant quotes from 1st to 20th Anniversary Edition.

### 1st & 2nd

> Recently, the Center for Disease Control, based in Atlanta,
>   has become deeply concerned over the increasing
>   incidents of AIDS being transmitted without apparent
>   intimacies of any sort. The CDC has begun to worry that
>   the virus no longer requires sexual contact to be spread.
>   Before news begins to spread, it has begun an enormous
>   investigation. 
> <sup>Vampire: The Masquerade 1st Edition, Chapter Witch Hunters, p31
>  Vampire: The Masquerade 2nd Edition, Chapter Witch Hunters, p 187</sup>

### Revised

> But immunity to disease doesn’t mean the vampires can
>   ignore diseases. Any illness that can be transmitted by the blood
>   is a potential problem for vampires, because they can carry the
>   illness and transmit it from victim to victim. Indeed, several
>   Kindred in Haiti and the US have become active carriers for the
>   HIV virus. By drinking from someone infected with the HIV
>   virus and then feeding on different victims, these vampires have
>   helped to spread an already rampant infection.
>
> In some fiefdoms any vampire found carrying HIV is locked
>   away for the good of the herd. In rare cases such carriers have
>   even been put to Final Death for spreading the disease. Such
>   plague-dogs are frowned upon heavily in the Camarilla, for not
>   only does disease threaten the human populace, but victims of
>   the disease might speak of their affiliation with vampires, putting
>   the Masquerade in grave danger.
> <sup>Vampire: The Masquerade Revised, p226</sup>

### V20

> There are certain advantages to being a walking
>   corpse. One of the biggest is a natural immunity to
>   most diseases. AIDS, SARS, cancer, syphilis, and other
>   illnesses mean little or nothing to the undead.
>   But immunity to disease doesn’t mean the vampires
>   can ignore diseases. Any illness that can be transmitted
>   by the blood is a potential problem for vampires,
>   because they can carry the illness and transmit it from
>   victim to victim. Indeed, several Kindred have become
>   active carriers for HIV. By drinking from someone infected
>   with HIV and then feeding on different victims,
>   these vampires have helped to spread a particularly
>   virulent infection.
>
> In some fiefdoms, any vampire found carrying such
>   a blood-borne disease is locked away for the good of
>   the herd. In rare cases such carriers have even been
>   put to Final Death for spreading disease. Such plaguedogs
>   are frowned upon heavily in the Camarilla, for
>   not only does disease threaten the human populace,
>   but victims of the disease might speak of their affiliation
>   with vampires, putting the Masquerade in grave
>   danger. Even the vampires of the Sabbat, with their
>   lack of concern for the herd, have begun to consider
>   regulations regarding disease carriers. 
> <sup>Vampire: The Masquerade 20th Anniversary, p295</sup>

### Actual Flaw

> DISEASE CARRIER (4-PT. FLAW)
>   Your blood carries a lethal and highly contagious disease. The
>   disease can be anything from rabies to HIV, and Kindred who drink
>   your blood have a 10 percent chance of becoming a carrier as well.
>   You must spend an extra blood point each night on awakening, or
>   you will begin manifesting symptoms of the disease (increased
>   chance to frenzy for rabies, reduced soak rolls for HIV, etc.). 
> <sup>Vampire: The Masquerade Revised, p298</sup>
> <sup>Vampire: The Masquerade 20th Anniversary, p483</sup>

Answer (score 8):

### In Fifth Edition, the vampire doesn’t suffer, but future victims can still be infected.

The *Vampire: the Masquerade* 5th edition core rulebook says the following under the "Dangers to the Blood" heading (p. 221):

> Even should they contract a disease from infected human blood, they pass it on to the kine they feed upon, while the germs die in their own system.

In this edition, vampires are unaffected by human diseases, though they may carry the disease and infect others they feed on in the future.